# Default height and width of inner forms

Tags: java, gwt

There is a problem in displaying the inner forms on different fire fox versions when developed in gwt.The height of  the form seems to change though the default width and height has been set.Is there any possible solution in which we can obtain the default width and the height of the inner forms which wont change when there are different versions of firefox?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, you set inner form's default height and width in fixed pixel. You should change it in percentage. Your inner form's height and width are based on your outer panel's height and width.

Comment: How to override the getDefaultWidth() and getDefaultHeight() n the implementer class.I used the following to implement it using pixels:@Override
    public int getDefaultWidth() {
       
        return 756;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefaultHeight() {
        return 440;
    }